# apt-get install fails with Not Found error because package removed from repository

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, libpng

I've been attempting to install the package `r-base` on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr and there's a package dependency that became broken in the last week.

My commands are as follows:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
apt-get install -y r-base-dev
...
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libpng12-dev amd64 1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Fetched 92.8 MB in 28s (3262 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-dev_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get install -y r-base-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I have attempted to pass `--fix-missing` and `--ignore-missing` but it still fails.

It appears that the package was removed on Jan 8, 2016 due to a security patch: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcepub/5711916/+listing-archive-extra

Looking at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/ confirms that the ubuntu2.14.04.**1** file is not there but 1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.**2** is present.

How do I fix that?
My goal is to get `r-base` to install.

If I could somehow make it use the version "2" file instead of "1" it would presumably find the file and proceed happily, but I'm not sure how to make apt-get do that.

Alternatively, maybe it's possible to update the dependency list on my side? Or is it up to the `r-base` maintainers to do so?

Or third, is it possible to add a repository that still has the old package? I'm not running on an AMD processor, so I shouldn't need this particular package at runtime anyway.

**Update:**
The solution that worked for me was to explicitly remove the package with the broken dependency, download the updated version, and re-install it before running `apt-get update`.

```
$ apt-get remove -y libpng12-0
$ curl -O http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2_amd64.deb
$ dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2_amd64.deb
$ apt-get update -y
```

The problem apparently doesn't have much to do with the `r-base` or `r-base-dev` packages, even though `r-base-dev` incidentally depends on `libpng12`.

Comment: Read [this man page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README) yet?

Comment: I don't understand if your goal is to install `r-base` why are you installing `r-base-dev`?

Comment: @ErnestA good question. I don't necessarily need `r-base-dev`. However I re-tried with `apt-get install -y r-base` instead and hit the same error when it tries to install the libpng12 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this problem will probably fix itself in a couple of days.  However if you can't wait, here's what you can do.

First, find out which version of `libpng` the package you want to install depends on.

```
$ apt-cache depends r-base
r-base
  Depends: r-base-core
  Depends: r-recommended
  Recommends: r-base-html
  Recommends: r-doc-html
  Suggests: ess
 |Suggests: r-doc-info
  Suggests: r-doc-pdf
```

`r-base` itself does not depend on `libpng` but `r-base-core` probably does.

```
$ apt-cache depends r-base-core | grep png
  Depends: libpng12-0
```

Now we want to know which specific version of `libpng`

```
$ apt-cache show r-base-core
... libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) ...
```

If you locate this package in Ubuntu's repositories, you can
download it and try to install it manually.

```
$ wget <url>
$ sudo dpkg -i <filename>
```

and then install `r-base` with `apt-get install r-base`.  However if `dpkg`
refuses to install `libpng` you should not force it, because it means the
package is not installable and it would break other dependencies.

Comment: This answer led me to my ultimate solution, which was to remove the existing libpng12-0 package, download the new libpng12-0 .deb, and install it with `dpkg` before running `apt-get update`. I'll update the question with the code block.