# In Docker, apt-get install fails with "Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ ... 404 Not Found" errors. Why? How can we get past it?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

My team uses Docker (with `ubuntu:14.04` base image) for local development and we often have to rebuild some or all of our images. But we often get failures downloading packages with `apt-get install`, even immediately after running `apt-get -y update`. For instance, today I see

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libxml2 amd64 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libxml2-dev amd64 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Fetched 84.7 MB in 1min 6s (1281 kB/s)
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-dev_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Aborting install.
```

Apparently the specific version of a particular package has been deleted from the archive and replaced with a slightly differently named patch version. For instance, the above error is looking for `libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb` but the version on the server is `libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb`.

Often this is solvable by removing the base image (`docker rmi ubuntu:14.04`) and rebuilding; the newly downloaded ubuntu image has the correct patch number and finds the right archive file. But even this doesn't always work -- probably due to a delay between a new minor upgrade to Ubuntu's dependency db and the deployment of that new `ubuntu:14.04` image onto Docker Hub.

We've tried using `apt-get` flags `--fix-missing` and `--fix-broken` and those don't consistently work either.

Any other ideas?

[apt-get install fails with Not Found error because package removed from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778262/apt-get-install-fails-with-not-found-error-because-package-removed-from-reposito) is a similar problem but the accepted answer is unacceptable because it's not possible to be automated. Our daily development process, including automatic build and deploy, is all scripted and using Docker and it's not practical to hack around inside a Dockerfile every time a particular archive goes missing (then remove the hack after a few hours or days).

---

In response to @prateek05, here's the `/etc/apt/sources.list` from the official `ubuntu:14.04` docker image:

```
root@72daa1942714:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
```

Comment: Do you always do `apt-get update` before any `apt-get install`?

Comment: yes, our base dockerfile starts with `RUN apt-get -y update`

Comment: Is this normally in a `docker build` or on the command line? What do you use to bust the docker build cache when rebuilding?

Comment: When this happens I use `docker rmi ubuntu:14.04` and then `docker build` downloads a fresh image and builds without cache from then on.

Comment: For a `docker build` to fail like this it must be attempting an `apt-get install` step rather than using the build cache. So is this occurring when devs make edits to the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Could you post a sample `Dockerfile`? The ordering could contribute

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You have stated that your Dockerfile contains `RUN apt-get -y update` as its own `RUN` instruction.  However, due to [build caching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache), if all changes to the Dockerfile occur later in the file, when `docker build` is run, Docker will reuse the intermediate image created the last time `RUN apt-get -y update` executed instead of running the command again, and so any recently-added or -edited `apt-get install` lines will be using old data, leading to the errors you've observed.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Pass the `--no-cache` option to `docker build`, forcing every statement in the Dockerfile to be run every time the image is built.
2. Rewrite the Dockerfile to combine the `apt-get` commands in a single `RUN` instruction: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install foo bar ...`.  This way, whenever the list of packages to install is edited, `docker build` will be forced to re-execute the entire `RUN` instruction and thus rerun `apt-get update` before installing.

The [Dockerfile best practices page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) actually has [an entire section on `apt-get` commands in Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get).  I suggest you read it.

Comment: NOTE - you only need to use the flag --no-cache ONCE to force a purge then that flag can be removed for subsequent docker build for same image ... handy/faster when repeating docker build for other reasons

Comment: Interestingly `--no-cache` worked but I already had `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...` and that hadn't been enough.

Comment: I have pass `--no-cache` parameter with any frequency?

Comment: ```docker build -t docker/test:latest . --no-cache``` This is what to use. Place this flag at  end of your build command.

Answer (score 17):

The issue could be potentially with the ubuntu sources

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list`

If you see `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main universe restricted multiverse` , that could be the potential issue.

Fix that by replacing it with `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse`

Alternatively it could be the mirror itself doesn't respond. `archive.ubuntu.com`

```
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.152
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.161
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.149
```

Replace archive.ubuntu.com with a more trusted mirror say `us.archive.ubuntu.com`

```
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.23
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.26
```

---

(edit by the oiriginal asker):

Thanks, prateek05! My Dockerfile now starts:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN sed -i'' 's/archive\.ubuntu\.com/us\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -y update
```

and it seems to be working. But since this is a sporadic issue, only time will tell...

Comment: in sources.list i see lots of settings I don't undersand :-) -- `trusty main restricted`, `trusty universe`, `trusty-security main restricted`, `trusty-security universe`, but no `multiverse` (except a commented-out one)... what should I change, exactly?

Comment: the contents look fine. It may be due to the mirror resolution. You get a mirror which isn't responding. To resolve that specify a mirror directly e.g. change everyhwere from archive.ubuntu.com to us.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: this line `RUN sed -i'' 's/archive\.ubuntu\.com/us\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list` is all that was needed to fix it.. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was caused by the parent image since it had not cleared the apt cache properly.

I solve the problem including cleaning commands before the first apt update ...

```
RUN apt clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt update && \
    ...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Found something that works!

So I found this:
https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5682159.html

The solution is to create a `pinning_file` with the contents

```
# Written by ubuntu-advantage-tools
Package: *
Pin: release o=UbuntuESM, n=trusty
Pin-Priority: never
```

Then add

```
COPY pinning_file /etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu-esm-infra-trusty
```

To you `Dockerfile` before you run the `sudo apt-get -y update`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error only after adding some extra arguments to `apt-get` to deal with http issues:

```
sudo apt-get \
  -o Acquire::BrokenProxy="true" \
  -o Acquire::http::No-Cache="true" \ 
  -o Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth="0" install \
    ignition
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me ...

I had the statements in two lines, but when i merged to one it worked (don't know if it was cache related ...)

it was

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Install tools && libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils iputils-ping nano wget dialog \
    build-essential git zip  \
```

And then i changed to

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils nano wget \
    git zip  \
    mysql-client \
```

Answer (score -3):

Using FTP sources works 100% of the time.

```
RUN echo \
   'deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\n \
    deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main\n \
    deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\n' \
    > /etc/apt/sources.list
```