# Dockerfile.test can not fetch some archives

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I try to execute `docker build -t test-image -f Dockerfile.test .` for my tests:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

RUN apt update && apt install -y build-essential libffi-dev libssl-dev

RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install poetry

# Install project-specific apt dependencies
RUN apt install -y cargo texlive texlive-lang-french texlive-latex-extra

RUN mkdir -p \
    /app/src \
    /app/workdir \
    /app/secrets \
    /app/storage \
    /app/static \
    /app/media \
    /app/log

WORKDIR /app/src

ADD poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/src/
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
RUN poetry install -vv --no-dev
RUN poetry install -vv
ENV PATH="/app/src/.venv/bin:$PATH"

ADD . /app/src/

RUN make test
```

I have the following errors:

```
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.3-2+deb10u4_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.3-2+deb10u4_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7_3.7.3-2+deb10u4_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/c/cups/libcups2_2.2.10-6+deb10u7_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/c/cups/libcupsimage2_2.2.10-6+deb10u7_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.1.0+git191117-2~deb10u7_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/ghostscript/libgs9-common_9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u7_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/ghostscript/libgs9_9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u7_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.170.132 80]
#8 30.57 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is it a cache problem ? Can I clean the cache in the `Dockerfile.test` ?

Comment: It is likely a cache problem.  It's important to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in the same command.  In your case, if the first `RUN` command was cached and the second wasn't, you could see an out-of-date APT index, which would result in these 404 errors.  The best approach would just be to combine the two `RUN` lines into a single `apt-get install` invocation.

Comment: If that is in fact your problem, also see [In Docker, apt-get install fails with "Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ ... 404 Not Found" errors. Why? How can we get past it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706635/in-docker-apt-get-install-fails-with-failed-to-fetch-http-archive-ubuntu-com)

Comment: Thx for the answer, I added `apt clean all` before the `apt update` and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the `RUN apt update && apt install -y build-essential libffi-dev libssl-dev` by `RUN apt clean all && apt update && apt install -y build-essential libffi-dev libssl-dev` and it fixed the problem.